# Slow and Fast tokenizer gives different outputs(sentencepiece tokenizer)

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, tokenization

When i use T5TokenizerFast(Tokenizer of T5 arcitecture), the output is expected as follows:

```
['▁', '</s>', '▁Hello', '▁', '<sep>', '</s>']
```

But when i use normal tokenizer, it starts to split special token "/s>" as follows:

```
['▁</', 's', '>', '▁Hello', '<sep>', '</s>']
```

**And this is print of not fast tokenizer**:

```
PreTrainedTokenizer(name_or_path='', vocab_size=60000, model_max_len=1000000000000000019884624838656, is_fast=False, padding_side='right', truncation_side='right', special_tokens={'eos_token': '</s>', 'unk_token': '<unk>', 'pad_token': '<pad>'})
```

**For fast** :

```
PreTrainedTokenizerFast(name_or_path='', vocab_size=60000, model_max_len=1000000000000000019884624838656, is_fast=True, padding_side='right', truncation_side='right', special_tokens={'eos_token': '</s>', 'unk_token': '<unk>', 'pad_token': '<pad>'})
```

Code that i am using to produce these outputs:

```
tokenizer = T5TokenizerFast('new_sp.model', extra_ids=0)
tokenizer.add_tokens(['<sep>'])
print(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(tokenizer.encode("</s> Hello <sep>")))
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this is a bug in the huggingface transformers library. Have you checked if there is a similar issue on their github? I see there are a number of issues regarding discrepancies between the fast and not fast tokenizers (see [this](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/17051)).

Comment: @noe Yes, i am trying them right now. When i got the results i will update my question. Thanks noe :)